# How to initialize or access packageManager out from coroutineContext?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-package-managers, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Jetpack Compose project were I can access a `coroutineContext` object only. No `context` available here.

How can I access or initialize android.content.pm.PackageManager ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the context object from `ContextAmbient.current`, using that you can get the PackageManager

Example:

```
val context = ContextAmbient.current
val packageManager = context.packageManager
```

Comment: Getting context now is `val context = LocalContext.current`

Answer (score 1):

To get context in Jetpack Compose:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

And to get packageManager from the context:

```
val packageManager = context.packageManager
```

So, if you just want packageManager you can use this:

```
val packageManager = LocalContext.current.packageManager
```

And for your information, `LocalContext.current` is a composable and need to be called in a composable context.